# Java r2dbc client execute sql and use returned id for next execute

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, r2dbc

I use r2dbc client with postgresql and I would like to call in one transaction 2 inserts(use id of first query) like:

```
      client.execute("INSERT INTO place(id,city) VALUES(:id, :city)")
    .bind("id", "nextval('place_id_seq')")
    .bind("city", place.getCity())
    .fetch().rowsUpdated())
    )
    .then(client.execute("INSERT INTO place_category VALUES (:place_id, :category_id);")
      .bind("place_id", <PREVIOUS_ID OF INSERT>)
      .bind("category_id", place.getCategoryId())
      .fetch().rowsUpdated())
    .then();
```

I don't know how to get @Id of first insert <PREVIOUS_ID OF INSERT>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first statement, add an extra filter to return the id fields.

```java
 .filter((statement, executeFunction) -> statement.returnGeneratedValues("id").execute())
```

Check my example of [Save](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/database-client/src/main/java/com/example/demo/PostRepository.java#L72) and [Query](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/database-client/src/main/java/com/example/demo/PostRepository.java#L64).

And there is a [JUnit test case](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/database-client/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostRepositoryTest.java#L52) for demo connectting them together.

BTW: I was using the DatabaseClient in Spring 5.3 for these samples.